# A question on quadratic equations.. Given below in the picture.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, roots, quadratics

[image: This is a picture of the question]

PLease also tell how u got to the answer as I want to know the way to solve further questions

Comment: The midpoint of the two roots is the $x$-coordinate of the vertex of the parabola $y=a(b-c)x^2+b(c-a)x+c(a-b)$.

Comment: What have you tried in order to find that other root? Please show your work so far, and where you got stuck. If you didn't get stuck, you shouldn't be asking this, at least in this way.

Comment: @david ..I have showed what I worked and posted it as   answer to the question after taking help from the previous responses........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the product of the two roots, say $\;1,w\;$ and use Viete's formulae:

$$w=1\cdot w=\frac{c(a-b)}{a(b-c)}$$

Comment: Thank You for the quick answer... Thats actually what I neded..

Answer (score 2):

By [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), letting $\alpha$ be the other root,
$$1+\alpha=-\frac{b(c-a)}{a(b-c)}\iff \alpha=-\frac{b(c-a)}{a(b-c)}-1=\frac{c(a-b)}{a(b-c)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have worked out Thanks to the above two answers.........

[image: answer]